# how to run the event of user control not regular

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control with some buttons (tmNewItem, tmEdit, tmInsert)

I write a clickButton event for them.

for example:

```
    public void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnNew.Enabled = false;
        btnEdit.Enabled = false;
    }
```

I used this user control in another project and write another method for the buttons and assign it to the usr control:

```
    public void DTedit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void UserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DT_Navigator.btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler(DTedit);
    }
```

and now, when I run the project and press btnEdit button, the first time, btnEdit_Click will execute and after that DTedit. can i change it? I mean the first time DTedit (that I define it in my project) run, and after it btnEdit_Click (that I define it in the user control) run?
how can I do that?

Comment: just remove the handler by using `-=`. ie. `DT_Navigator.btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler(DTedit);`

Comment: It is very bad practice to call an event from another event.  I'd suggest you re-think what it is that you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Nimesh can u explain more? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void DTedit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Place your code here
     DT_Navigator.btnCancel.Click -= new EventHandler(DTedit);  //This will remove handler from the button click and it will not be executed next time.
}

private void UserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DT_Navigator.btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler(DTedit);
}
```

**Suggested Code**

```
//User control

public event CancelEventHandler BeginEdit;
public event EventHandler EndEdit;


private btnYourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancelEventArgs e = new CancelEventArgs();
    e.Cancel = false;
    if (BeginEdit != null)
        BeginEdit(this, e);
    if (e.Cancel == false)
    {
        if (EndEdit != null)
            EndEdit(this, new EventArgs);

        //You can place your code here to disable controls
    }
}
```

Comment: @Elahe Why dont you move the logic that is in `DTedit` into its own method. Then call that method from both `UserControl_Load` and `DTedit`. A much more scalable and maintainable way to do things

Comment: @paqogomez I want that if logic code in DTedit done successfuly, then btnEdit_Click done. for example: in DTedit I check that user enter true data or not? if its true, I disable btnEdit in  btnEdit_Click

Comment: So, you want to set execution order first DTedit then btnEdit_Click?

Comment: Why would you disable a button in its click event?  The user would have to press it for it to be disabled, but you've already determined that you want it disabled.  That doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Then why don't you create separate method for validation? for example create two event. BegineEdit and EndEdit.

Comment: @Nimesh, like it!  Hopefully OP will catch the vision.

Comment: @Nimesh I cant creat a validation method in user control, because I should check my database and I dont have access to my data base in userControl

Comment: @paqogomez I used the user control in many forms that I dont like to disable buttons in click event at all the forms!

Comment: You just need to create event in UserControl defined in above example and that will be called in your form. So basically your validation code will be placed in ur form not in user control.

Comment: @Nimesh I explain my project simply in another way: I have a textBox(txtName), I have a userContrl with btnInsert. when the user fill the txtName, I check that the name dosent be in database, if its not, and user press btnInsert, so the new name add to my database and btnInsert will be disable. but if the name is not unique in database, btnInsert will be enable and the name dosent save in database. disable and enable btnInsert is in click event in user control.

Comment: @Elahe lets chat in [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48048/net-devs)